# Enter key not working in HTML form using TWebBrowser component

Tags: delphi, twebbrowser

I made a php web page with simple text form and tried to browse this page with application in Delphi using TWebBrowser component. Problem is that I cannot hit the Enter key in this form to get a newline. I can type in, mouse is working fine, but Enter key is not working. In any other browser it is working fine. 
Perhaps it may have something to do with TWebBrowser's OnEnter event handler? I really can't figure out how to fix this.

Comment: can you make a small static webpage that reproduces this error? I think I may have a  solution.

Answer (score -2):

```
procedure TForm1.FormKeyPress(Sender: TObject;var Key: Char);
begin 
  //Don't forget to set the Keypreview property 
  //of the form to true!
  if (Key=#13) then begin 
    Key := #0; 
    Keybd_Event(VK_LCONTROL, 0, 0, 0); //Ctrl key down 
    Keybd_Event(Ord('M'), MapVirtualKey(Ord('M'), 0),0, 0); // 'M' key down 
    Keybd_Event(Ord('M'), MapVirtualKey(Ord('M'), 0), KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0); // 'M' Key up 
    Keybd_Event(VK_LCONTROL, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP,  0); // Ctrl key up 
    Keybd_Event(VK_CANCEL, 0, 0, 0);
  end; 
end;
```

// source: http://beensoft.blogspot.com/2007/10/fooling-around-with-twebbrowser-4.html
// Keypreview change true